# Trying to install pip on mac OS 10.6.8

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip on my old macbook by running the command sudo easy_install pip
Once I ran this it asked me for my password and appeared to install but I then got the message:

Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')

I then thought I would double check if it installed using: pip -V
which returned -bash: pip: command not found
Help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

run this command: brew install python
to install the newest python first.

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried that in terminal and I got: - bash:brew: command  not found

Comment: then you needs to install brew first.
maybe you can find what you need in this website https://brew.sh
the install command is:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```